# Show that if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq b$, the intersection of the $\epsilon$ neighborhoods of a and b is $\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I know the $\epsilon$-neighbordhood for a $\in \mathbb{R}$ is defined as the set $V_\epsilon(a)$ of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that |x-a| < $\epsilon$. To prove that the intersection of two neighborhoods for two different elements is the empty set I think I need to show that there are no elements that exist in both neighborhoods. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $\varepsilon < |a-b|$.

Comment: Or perhaps $\epsilon<\frac{|a-b|}{2}$.

Comment: @paw88789: Right, that's a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily true. For example: Take $2,\frac{3}{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ then, for $\epsilon =0.6$ we have, $N_\epsilon(2)=(2-0.6,2+0.6)=(1.4,2.6)$ and $N_\epsilon(\frac{3}{2})=(\frac{3}{2}-0.6 ,\frac{3}{2}+.6)=(0.9,2.1)$ and clearly, $(1.4, 2.6) \cap(0.9, 2.1)=(1.4,2.1)\neq\emptyset$

Your statement need some correction. The following statement is true.

> If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq b$ then, there exists neighborhoods $N_{\epsilon_1}(a)$ , $N_{\epsilon_2}(b)$ of $a, b$ respectively, such that $N_{\epsilon_1}(a)\cap N_{\epsilon_2}(b)=\emptyset$.